# JavaScript Date Function

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following function that changes a calendar selection at a set time during the day (all code works perfectly).
However, I'd like to modify it slightly so that on a SATURDAY the dd=dd+1 becomes dd=dd+2, because I want to skip Sunday. Can anyone help?

```
$(function() {       
var dd = 0
if (<%= currentHour %> > <%= cutoffHour %>) {
dd = dd + 1; // go one day in the future
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood you correctly but change `dd = dd + 1;` into something like this:

```
dd = (dd == 5) ? dd + 2 : dd + 1
```

I don't know how do you determine SATURDAY but I guess as a numeric value where Saturday is `5` or `6`.

### EIDT:

```
if (6 == new Date().getDay()) {
    dd += 2;
}
```

Comment: I want to add something like:
cc = getDay()
If cc = 6
dd = dd +2
This would have to come after the time check, just don't know the correct way to write it!!